# Does macOS show battery health for third-party replacement batteries?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery

My late 2013 13" retina MacBook Pro's battery is on its last legs, and I need to replace it soon.  I'm thinking of buying a replacement battery kit from iFixit, and I'm wondering if macOS will be able to show battery health (as in the image below) for the new battery, considering that it'll be a third-party battery.  Can anyone let me know about this?

[image: macOS battery health]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The batteries I have used from iFixit do show the battery health and work functionally the same as the apple battery.  I have yet to be disappointed in my purchases from iFixit.

Comment: I concur - I haven't seen any MacBook model not display battery health info from a 3rd party battery (although that may change in future based on what Apple is starting to do with iPhones). However, what I have noticed with some 3rd party batteries is they don't last very long at all and the battery condition reports this appropriately. So if you're going to buy a 3rd party battery, spend a little more and buy it from a reputable seller.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for letting me know.  I was curious about this, since I've seen people saying that iPhones don't show battery health for iFixit batteries.